# How to wait for the options to be clickable in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I am writing a script right now to take information from a website and there is a lot of select/option fields. The problem is, currently I am checking to see if the select box is clickable before trying to click the options but this works about 15% of the time. Here is the line that waits for the element to be clickable:

```
schoolbox = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "clCampusSelectBox"))))
```

How do I wait for the options below this select element to be clickable?

Thanks

Edit: here are the dropdowns: https://shop.bookstore.ubc.ca/courselistbuilder.aspx

Comment: When it doesn't work 85% of the time, what does it do? What does "doesn't work" mean? Does it throw an error? Does it click some other element?

Comment: I believe the issue is 15% of the time the options are loading in time to be clicked. The other 85% of the time when it tries to click on the options they arent loaded yet

Comment: So why don't you wait for the page to finish loading before trying to access these elements?

Comment: It's basically 5 nested select boxes, so each time I select an option I have to wait for the next options to be available 5 times in a row

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Are you saying you aren't waiting because it's too difficult?

Comment: Oh.. do you mean wait for the page to load after each selection?

Answer (score 1):

Clickable element has to be visible and enabled. The `<option>` elements under the `<select>` are usually not visible, so "is clickable" check will fail. I suggest you wait for the dropdown to be visible and then use [select class](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.select) to select the option

```
schoolbox = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "clCampusSelectBox"))))
schoolbox.select_by_value("someValue")
```

Comment: These options are visible. I will update the ticket with the page.

Comment: @joe Only in "CAMPUS" all the options are visible. In the other tables only some of them are visible.

Answer (score -1):

I am writing this to inform you that waiting for select_list and waiting for options are two different thing! Why are you waiting for select_list to be clickable? You need to wait for option,right? I don't know python, I am using WATIR(language is Ruby) where waiting for select_list and then waiting for option will automatically happen, you don't have write anything

This simple code is enough

```
b.select_list(:id,'q').select 'hi'
```

It will automatically wait for select list to be present and then it will wait for option to be present, you don't have to do anything deliberately.

But if I want to write the code to wait for select_list, then I will write

```
b.select_list(:id,'q').wait_until_present.select 'hi'
```

If I want to write the code to wait for option in the select_list then I will write

```
b.select_list(:id,'q').option(:text,'hi').wait_until_present.select
```

If I want to wait for both, then I will write

```
b.select_list(:id,'q').wait_until_present.option(:text,'hi').wait_until_present.select
```

but these are not necessary in WATIR because it automatically waits for everything.

So all you need to know is whether to wait for select_list or to wait for option because in certain condition your select list option will be populated according to some condition.

Comment: Hmm, OK, I think I need to some more investigation on how to select the options. But I have not been able to find a good example of something similar

Comment: The OP is using Python, not Ruby.

Comment: @Guy Yes, I know that's why I haven't given the answer, my answer is to make him understand about the two things one is to wait for select_list and another is to wait for option,he was not aware of that until he reads my paragraph.

Comment: @Guy I don't python but I am clearly aware of the problem and I know the way to solve this problem in WATIR so I gave him the idea about what's happening there.

Comment: @RAJ Still, answers should contain code in the language used by the OP. There are different implementations. For example, in Python you don't have functionality like `wait_until_present.option`

Comment: I absolutely understand that's the foremost reason my comment was,  I asked him to find a similar way. I gave the way. By the please read comment before you downvote!

Comment: @joe Okay, I suggest you to use WATIR if possible though I am not willing to force you! And also WATIR is the wrapper around selenium-webdriver. It does all the necessary job before it calls the selenium ruby bindings. So most of the challenges which you face will not occur there since WATIR wrapper itself will take care of everything.